# Raspberry Pi Crontab Python subprocess.Popen not showing

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi, chromium, popen

**Brief**

I am a beginner at raspberry-pi and am currently working on a project, which requires to run a python script at boot.

A part of the script will check for some conditions and then open the chromium-browser (using subprocess.Popen()), if necessary.

**Codes**

Below is the short extract of my python script (the sleep is for me to check that the script is running):

```
import shlex, subprocess
import time

command = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser "https://www.google.com" -start-maximized --no-sandbox'
args = shlex.split(command)
browser = subprocess.Popen(args)
time.sleep(1000)
```

The code seems to be executed correctly when I am running from the **Terminal**:

```
python /home/pi/Desktop/test_popen_browser.py
```

However, when I try to schedule it on the crontab (edited using Terminal with the "**sudo crontab -e**" command), it does not seem to work (the python script is being executed, but no browser window is opened):

```
@reboot python /home/pi/Desktop/test_popen_browser.py &
```

**Question**

Have tried to search online for answers, and I think the environment variables are causing the problems. But I just cant find out what exactly should I set the environment variables to be.

Does anyone knows where the problem lies?

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the GUI manager has not started when your script is started at reboot. Instead of running your script as cronjob place it in /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@point-rpi
/usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/test_popen_browser.py
unclutter -idle 30
```

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for the answer. im gonna try that now. what does the "unclutter -idle 30" do?

Comment: You need not add it its for hiding mouse pointer. Just add /usr/bin/python /home/pi/Desktop/test_popen_browser.py this line.

Comment: alright! thank you so much! the popen seems to work! however, because there are other functions in the script, i need to test all the functionalities. do you know if the scripts that run in the /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart file are running as root?

Comment: They run with user privileges. For running script with root privilages  place the same line in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Ok try adding in /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart file then rename the /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart file